# Get random value from HashMap

Tags: random, hashmap

I want to get random value of HashMap, but only from one key.

This is how i build my HashMap. Every Key has multiple values.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
for (.....) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

        map.put(KEY_1, parser.getValue(e, KEY_1));
        map.put(KEY_2, parser.getValue(e, KEY_2));
// adding HashList to ArrayList
        items.add(map);
}
```

So key "KEY_1" has multiple values so do "KEY_2".
Now i want to get random value using key "KEY_1". How to do that ?

EDIT: I think i know where is problem, although dont know yet how to fix that.
Problem is defining size(); I need somehow get size not from all HashMap items like "items.size();" but something more similar to "items.KEY_1.size();"

With this code getting NullPointerException

```
int index = random.nextInt(items.size());
    HashMap<String, String> randomitem = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    randomitem = items.get(index);
    System.out.println(randomitem.get(KEY_1));
```

With this code im able to get value not random:

```
int index = 2;
    HashMap<String, String> randomitem = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    randomitem = items.get(index);
    System.out.println(randomitem.get(KEY_1));
```

**EDIT:** With this code i can get random values but i get values from all keys. How to get values only from one key ?

```
Random rand = new Random();
indexx = rand.nextInt(items.size());
System.out.println(items.get(indexx));
```

**Solved** With this code i can get random value from certain key.

```
Random rand = new Random();
indexx = rand.nextInt(items.size());
HashMap<String, String> randomitems = items.get(indexx);

System.out.println(randomitems.get(KEY_1));
```

Comment: what is the format of your string in which you store your values ?

Comment: The way you've specialized your HashMap a key only has one value of string type.  If you want it to have multiple string values you'll need to change your specialization of HashMap to store a list of strings .